# How to change the writing direction in iPhone UITextView or UITextField

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, uitextview, right-to-left

Right now if you type something in a right to left language and tap and hold, the copy and paste menu will have an extra option for changing the writing direction form "left to right" to "right to left".

I want to set this option in the code so that my UITextView writing direction would be right to left by default.

Does anyone know how I can do that. I searched all over the web and SDK and tried everything with no luck. I would be grateful if anyone can help.

Answer (score 1):

check may be this will help you.

setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentRight;

Answer (score 1):

Hope this can help

divide the text in the UITextView by line,and change NSString from "left to right" to "right to left" is quite simple

Answer (score 0):

if you want set text writing direction right to left in uitextview

```
"your UITextview".makeTextWritingDirectionRightToLeft(true)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use something like:

Swift:

```
func makeTextWritingDirectionRightToLeft(_ sender: Any?)
```

Objective C:

```
(void)makeTextWritingDirectionRightToLeft:(id)sender;
```

Look it up in the Method Reference